# control shield with phone

Tags: remote-control, nvidia-shield

I am thinking about buying an NVidia shield for my TV. Can I control this shield with e.g. my android phone or an android tablet using something like this app: `com.google.android.tv.remote`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the reviews on the app you asked about and from searching a little bit on google. Yes. You can control the shield tv from your phone. According to Nvidia, the shield tv comes with the controller which can of course control it as well.

**Edit** Adding a link to the app in question. Which can be found [here.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.tv.remote&hl=en)